# How to use OmniSharp C# LSP with Mason in nvim properly?

Tags: neovim, lsp, nvim-cmp

I have installed the fomlowing plugins:

- mason.nvim
- mason-lspconfig.nvim
- nvim-lspconfig
- nvim-cmp
- cmp-nvim-lsp

(I may have forgeotten to include something, but in any way I can use LSP with this setup with `lua_ls` for lua)

The problem is the following: I have installed `omnisharp` with `mason.nvim`, and loaded it. Its `:h lspconfig-all` says next:

> https://github.com/omnisharp/omnisharp-roslyn OmniSharp server based on Roslyn workspaces omnisharp-roslyn can be installed by downloading and extracting a release from here. OmniSharp can also be built from source by following the instructions here. OmniSharp requires the dotnet-sdk to be installed. By default, omnisharp-roslyn doesn’t have a cmd set. This is because nvim-lspconfig does not make assumptions about your path. You must add the following to your init.vim or init.lua to set cmd to the absolute path ($HOME and ~ are not expanded) of the unzipped run script or binary. For go_to_definition to work fully, extended textDocument/definition handler is needed, for example see omnisharp-extended-lsp.nvim

I have the following `omnisharp` import:

```lua
lspconfig.omnisharp.setup {
    capabilities = capabilities,
    cmd = { "dotnet", "/Users/vladyslav/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/omnisharp/libexec/OmniSharp.dll"},
}
```

When I open the `.cs` file, I get no completion. The `:LspInfo` says:

[image]

Project structure:

```
➜  Lab3.6_v1.0 tree -L 1
.
├── LaTeX
├── assemblyinfo.cs
├── delivery.txt
├── part.txt
├── program.cs
├── project.txt
├── report.pdf
├── supplier.txt
└── wnd.cs

2 directories, 8 files
```

Why I get no `omnisharp` completion? I managed the `lua_ls` and `clangd` to work for easy, so I am sure this is not a config issue, it have to be related to the way `lspconfig.omnisharp.setup` is called. Am I using the omnisharp wrong here?

My entire config in this state can be found here: https://github.com/Dolfost/dotfiles/tree/neovim/omnisharp-issue/nvim

## 13/01/23 Update

I found out that the problem is in the `rood_dir` detection. Next setup for `omnisharp` LSP is working but is too basic. It just takes current working directory as project root:

```
            lspconfig.omnisharp.setup {
                capabilities = capabilities,
                cmd = { "dotnet", vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/packages/omnisharp/libexec/OmniSharp.dll" },
                enable_import_completion = true,
                organize_imports_on_format = true,
                enable_roslyn_analyzers = true,
                root_dir = function ()
                    return vim.loop.cwd() -- current working directory
                end,
            }
```

Any suggestions to improve this function are welcome.

Comment: I'm personally using [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) to ensure the Vim current working directory is the project root (vim-rooter can be configured to search for special file like `.gitignore` or special subfolder like `.git` to find the root)